# What's the difference between colloquial and oral English?

Tags: differences, terminology

What is the difference between *colloquial* an *oral* in the phrases, *colloquial English* and *oral English*?

Comment: I like this question because the English language doesn't employ as strong a distinction between its oral and written forms as some other languages, like French (with written tenses and moods that simply don't exist orally, such as l'imparfait du subjonctif http://www.leconjugueur.com/frimparfaitsubjonctif.php). I believe (merely anecdotally) that this may have encouraged blurring the line somewhat between oral and colloquial/informal.

Comment: Uh, colloquial sex is not nearly as much fun?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Alternatively, for the linguists out there: *oral* refers *communication medium* whereas *colloquial* refers to *register*.

Considered this way, the concepts are not mutually exclusive: would you consider a speech (i.e., *oral* communication) given by Queen Elizabeth II colloquial? Surely not! Given by President Barack Obama? Quite possibly…

For another example: *colloquial* is in opposition to *formal* (among others), whereas *oral* is in opposition to *written*, *[signed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_language)*, *etc*.

Comment: In other words, a speech by President Obama is more likely to include *colloquial* English than a speech by Queen Elizabeth II, but both are equally *oral* English.

Answer (score 3):

"oral English" is any spoken English. "colloquial English" is informal, and may include language that might be unacceptable for printing.

Comment: +1 Furthermore, informal oral often employs colloquial language.

Answer (score 2):

Colloquial comes from the word conversation, specifically, according to the OED

```
 1. Of or pertaining to colloquy; conversational.
```

Perhaps a better way to phrase your question is - What is the difference between oral and conversational English.

Conversational English is typically oral, but oral English is not necessarily conversational.