# What's the difference between "informal", "colloquial", "slang", and "vulgar"?

Tags: differences, slang, formality, colloquialisms, offensive-language

It seems many people get confused about the differences (and similarities) between "colloquial" and "slang", so what exactly does each term apply to?

But to be even more thorough it seems to me we can also include a couple more terms which are often applied to language and arrange them into a scale from most acceptable to least acceptable: "informal" > "colloquial" > "slang" > "vulgar"

Are any two synonyms? Do they all overlap semantically or only with their closest neighbours? Or should some of them be seen as independently variable aspects of a word or utterance?

Finally, could each term apply equally as well to a word, a phrase, and a grammatical or syntactical usage?

**EDIT**

Perhaps I should've also included "nonstandard" - not sure whether it belongs to the left or the right of "slang" though.

Comment: There is another question which concentrates at the rightmost end of my scale and beyond: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27217/that-which-is-vulgar-obscene-or-profane-title-reflects-contents

Comment: There is also a question which compares colloquial and oral English: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21109/whats-the-difference-between-colloquial-and-oral-english

Comment: I've posted a followup question on the ambiguous senses of "vulgar": http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29889/differences-between-vulgar-and-coarse-crass-rough-rude-unrefined

Comment: What about vernacular: the language or dialect spoken by the ordinary people in a particular country or region.

Comment: @user64964: Vernacular and colloquial would probably be pretty close but vernacular would also touch on idiomatic. Might be worth asking another followup question.

Comment: Also related: [Differences among expression and idiom, as well as colloquial and vernacular](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/32390/2042).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**[Edited, with examples:]** There is some overlap between these terms. People will often even disagree whether a certain expression is best considered *informal,* or rather *colloquial*, etc. This is merely an attempt at cataloguing possible associations. If you have suggestions for improvement or refinement, do not hesitate.

**Informal**:

- This is the broadest, most neutral word. It just means that speech or writing is on the lower side of the *formal–middle–informal* spectrum. In informal situations, when your conduct is relaxed in all respects and etiquette matters less, you will use informal language accordingly.
- Varieties of language at lower or higher levels in the spectrum are often referred to as lower or higher **registers**, although the word *register* is not necessarily about high or low: it can also just be about varieties that are somehow different from the standard.
- Apart from that, it is neither negative nor positive; that's why it is the best term if you don't want to sound disapproving (and if *colloquial* is not an option).
- There are various degrees of (in)formality: it is usually not a yes–no distinction.
- Although perhaps higher-class people are sometimes expected to be in formal situations more often, and lower-class people are expected to care less about formality, there is no strict relation to perceived class. There are informal words or phrases that are frequently used by perceived 'higher classes' (*loo*), and, conversely, formal words that are not frequently used by same (*Milady, toilet*).

**Colloquial**:

> *Oxford English Dictionary*: **2.** *spec.* Of words, phrases, etc.: Belonging to common speech; characteristic of or proper to ordinary conversation, as distinguished from formal or elevated language. (The usual sense.)

- This is quite close to *informal*.
- It is mostly used with speech rather than writing, though not necessarily so.
- The word is also slightly stronger on average than *informal* (i.e. more informal).
- It suggests a yes–no qualification: saying *more colloquial* is not so common.
- It is usually neither positive nor negative, nor felt to be lower class.
- However, the euphemism "colloquial at best" is often used to mean that it is bad style, referring to a colloquialism used in the wrong setting.
- Because colloquial (and informal) language often varies locally or regionally, while formal language does so much less, it is sometimes associated with provincialisms or regionalisms. But I would consider this contingent, not essential to the term itself.

**Slang**:

- *Slang* can be a noun or an adjective; *slangy* means "resembling or constituting slang".
- It is more often negative than positive—but it can still easily be positive.
- In the *formal–middle–informal* spectrum, it is more informal than *colloquial* or *informal*.
- The word *slang* itself is a bit informal, while the other words on this page are not.

> *Oxford English Dictionary*: **1. a.** The special vocabulary used by any set of persons of a low or disreputable character; language of a low and vulgar type. [notice *vulgar* used ambiguously]

1. Originally, *slang* was language associated with low socio-economic class or character, and it is still used with that connotation, though by no means always.
2. A secondary sense has developed, that of general "group talk" in a mildly disapproving or mocking way—even if this group isn't lower class. This sense is now arguably more common than the first. It is often used ironically, as in *lawyer slang*.
3. A tertiary, entirely neutral sense, "any kind of non-standard group talk", is now commonly used in academia.

**Vulgar**:

- This means literally "of the people".The *Oxford English Dictionary* describes its development through the ages:

> **I. 3.** Commonly or customarily used by the people of a country; ordinary, vernacular. *In common use c 1525–1650; now arch.*

> **II. 9.** Belonging to the ordinary or common class in the community;
> not distinguished or marked off from this in any way; plebeian

> **II. 13.** Having a common and offensively mean character; coarsely commonplace; lacking in refinement or good taste; uncultured, ill-bred.

- It can now be used to describe language in two ways:

1. The old-fashioned sense is as (II. 9.) above. It is still in use in dictionaries, but less frequent elsewhere.
2. The modern sense is close to (II. 13.), "obscene" or "filthy" to a greater or lesser degree; the lower classes were supposed to be liable to such language, and this sub-sense of (1.) came to dominate the word. So this is obviously even less formal than *slang* in its lower-class sense. In dictionaries, *vulgar* could be (1.) or (2.).

Other relevant words:

**Jargon**: technical or academic language or terminology. This is usually perceived to be somewhat formal, and inaccessible to those outside the field in question.

**Vernacular**: refers to the native language of normal people, when a different language is used by some groups in society. So this is about different languages, not merely different registers or levels of formality. Usually, the non-vernacular language is used by the educated or higher classes, such as Latin until ca. the 19th century.

---

I will give a few examples, best description first:

> That **ain't** right.

- *slang*
- *informal*
- *vulgar* (1. of the common people), old-fashioned label
- perhaps *colloquial*

> I will **try and** convince her.

- slightly *informal*
- *colloquial*
- some might call this *slang* or *vulgar* (1.), but it isn't felt to be connected with lower class by most people, nor with certain specific groups

> That **sucks**.

- *slang*
- *vulgar* (2. obscene), old-fashioned label, because *suck* has lost its sexual connotation for many people
- *vulgar* (1. of the common people)
- *informal* (a bit too general)
- *colloquial* is possible, but not the best choice

> If I **was** rich, I'd go to London.

- *informal*
- *colloquial*, but many people "would never say *was*", in neither speech nor writing
- *slang* or *vulgar* (1. of the common people): probably not

Comment: @Cerberus: I was actually thinking of "vulgar" to mean "rough", "coarse", "unrefined" and that the "obscene" or "offensive" sense was incorrect, but it seems I am wrong and the term is quite fuzzy despite its use in dictionaries. I also thought of "slang" as a specific kind of trendy invented terminology not approved of by others and hence different to "coarse", "rough", "vulgar" though often one feature of that kind of unrefined speech.

Comment: I believe "colloquial" has connotations of "provincial" or "regional", i.e. informal language which is peculiar to a certain geographical area.

Comment: @hippietrail: Yeah these terms are quite complicated and fuzzy. Different people will describe them differently. I think you're right that the group thing is sometimes (not always) an added connotation to *slang*.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I'm not sure. There is overlap. It doesn't have that particular connotation to me. So you wouldn't say "try and" was colloquial?

Comment: @Cerberus: More context needed.  Sounds like an error-handling technique to me, usable in formal computer science writing.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I meant my example above (perhaps you didn't see my edit yet): *I will **try and** convince her.*

Comment: I don't want to discredit the thoroughness of this answer, but some of this is quite wrong; the definitions are either  evasive, inaccurate, or far too generalized. I don't feel this touches on the shades of meaning the question was looking for.

Comment: @Cerberus: Ahh, I see.  That does seem somewhat informal, a variant of "try to" that expresses confidence in a successful outcome ("I will try to convince her, and I will convince her.", thus "I will try and convince her.")  It doesn't seem like an idiom to me, rather it has a plain meaning; I wouldn't consider it a colloquialism.

Comment: @HaL: I know that many people have different opinions on the exact meaning of these words. I expected no less than disagreement from various sides. But I believe at least some people would have associations similar to the points I gave. If you have suggestions for improvement, please make them; especially "evasive" should be something I can work on.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I think opinions vary; consider these two answers: [Origins: “try and” over “try to” — how did we get there from here?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27008/origins-try-and-over-try-to-how-did-we-get-there-from-here/27024#27024) — [Difference between “try to do” and “try and do”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/456/difference-between-try-to-do-and-try-and-do)

Comment: @Cerebus. Fair enough. I really do appreciate the thought you've given the answer, but I feel there are a lot of etymological clues that were overlooked. For instance, Etymology Online suggests _informal_ once chiefly meant _irregular_, and wasn't used in the context of "without ceremony" until the 19th century. I also feel it's important to distinguish that _vulgar_ referred to, as you stated, "of the common people", but this meaning endured quite some time before it began to become associated with the "filth" and "obscenity" of that class.

Comment: @HaL: Okay, I don't disagree with either of your points. Feel free to edit them in, if you like. That history of *informal* is no doubt correct; but I wouldn't know how to connect that to the modern sense myself. I also agree with your characterization of *vulgar*; but I think I included that? If it's a general lack of history and etymology you're missing, by all means resolve it: I never got to that.

Comment: @Cerberus: "slang' is definitely not lower-socioeconomic specific. Read any P.G.Wodehouse to get a headful of upper-crust slang. 'slang' is closely related to 'jargon' and 'argot', specialized vocabulary for a subset of people within a dialect. Also, "ain't" is not slang (it's not specific to a subset of the dialect it occurs in). It _is_ informal, but it is __not old-fashioned__.

Comment: @Mitch: What you are referring to is the (newer) secondary sense of slang, which is perhaps most common. I have given it more emphasis; see if you can live with that. // Many people would call *ain't* slang in its primary sense. [An example.](http://www.wcu.edu/11837.asp) *Ain't* is also popular among certain groups and subcultures, qualifying for sense 2. // I have absolutely no idea why anyone should say it was "old fashioned".

Comment: @Cerberus: // the use of 'slang' at that website seems wrong, and doesn't follow what other sources say slang is. // I was mislead by your bullet point on "ain't": "vulgar (1. of the common people), old fashioned", it looks like you're saying that "ain't" is old-fashioned.

Comment: @Mitch: Wikipedia cites linguists suggesting the following as one of four possible criteria: ["It is a taboo term in ordinary discourse with people of a higher social status or greater responsibility."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slang#Defining_slang) // Oh! My mistake, edited.

Comment: Other labels include “coarse slang” and “taboo-word”. But I cannot see how anyone would call *ain’t” a bit of informal jargon.  Doesn’t make much sense to me.

Comment: @tchrist: Who called it that? *Ain't* ain't jargon, but it is informal.

Answer (score 4):

**Informal** - This is directly related to register. It is mostly dictated by social status. One would use formal language in formal setting, such as business functions or any time when you are speaking with members of high/higher society.

**Colloquial** - This is geographical. There is only one language in England: English. However, two people from different cities might have quite notable difficulty understanding each other in conversation due to colloquialisms. They are often related to the history of the given place and can be influenced by things such as prevalent industry, local surroundings and historical events.

**Slang** - This tends to be more social. The understanding of slang is usually restricted to a group of peers. This could be a small group or a large group. They could be from very different places and backgrounds. Slang is formed more through mutual understanding and often to intentionally create an element of exclusivity. Because of all these factors, slang tends to change constantly and often does not last long enough to enter into common usage. Though it's a slightly lazy example, consider how teenagers speak. Each generation tends to have it's own slang. It is not constant. It exists for that group of people at that time. It is essentially a type of jargon.

**Vulgar** - This is a little different to the other terms. Each of the others refers to a style of speaking that an individual might adopt and would affect all elements of speech. This term however, is restricted really to vocabulary. Linguistically speaking, if a person is vulgar, it means that they tend to use obscenities. It might also refer to their selection of crass or crude conversation topics.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Comments from downvoters would be very much appreciated...

Comment: I don't know why people would've downvoted this answer but for me there are two surprises both of which have already come up in other people's answers: 1) That colloquial is related to region rather than related to colloquy and 2) That vulgar would only mean obscene and not rough/coarse/unrefined, though your addittion of crass/crude perhaps bridges that gap.

Comment: You're welcome ;-) As you are also welcome to correct my own typos as well whenever you find some.  I know there are still a lot of them lurking in the depth of EL&U archives.

Answer (score 0):

There are slight differences between these four terms:

Informal has to do with speech or writing that is not strictly formal, or strictly standard. Colloquialism refers to informal speech or writing. Slang is a form of colloquialism, but slang isn't necessarily vulgari.e. 'dog and bone' for 'telephone', or 'bouncer' for soomething really good.

Vulgar is anything that is offensive, in formal, or informal speech. It could include slang that refers to indecent subjects i.e. 'frigging', or formal speech that refers to indecent subjects  i.e.'incest'

Comment: example of vulgar in formal speech? :)

Comment: I think of "vulgar" as the opposite of "refined" so while not the opposite of "formal" it's hard to think of a way to be both formal and vulgar. Perhaps a comical rewording of "You can stick this job up your arse!" into "Dear Sir, please insert this job anally"? (-:

Comment: "Incest" may describe a vulgar concept, but I don't agree that it is *itself* a vulgar word.

Comment: I'll try to think of another one. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score -1):

After attending an Advanced Placement College Board English Literature seminar in 2010, the presenter (sorry, can't recall her name but she was a professor at a Pennsylvania State College, maybe IUP) suggested these distinctions:

- informal — what the majority of a culture uses for writing/speaking;
- colloquial — words from a specific region  (*y'all* for American South, *yinz for Pittsburgh);
- slang — words from a time period  (*groovy* for 60's, *rad* for 80's).

Never did get any second source to verify, but these have been good discussion points in my classroom for teaching about this topic. What do you all think?

Comment: There is some truth here, but much confusion. Yes, *informal* is typically used for expressions which the majority of a culture knows and uses; but specifically it means expressions which are not used in formal contexts. A *colloquialism* is not regional but conversational, typically with an informal context ("colloquy" means "conversation"). *Slang* does not mean from a time period; it means a very informal expression often known only to a specific group of people. Slang terms often have short lifetimes and so can *sometimes* be associated in our minds with time periods.