# differences vernacular vs. colloquial

Tags: differences

What is the difference between the words vernacular and colloquial? Is vernacular closer to jargon?

A quick search reveals that colloquial refers to informal spoken language while vernacular refers to some sort of native language of a place. Is that the only difference?

Comment: Quote from 'Help': "Try a dictionary" - "Be sure to mention the research you've done and what you're still hoping to learn!" What searching have you done? What does that suggest? And why does it not answer your question>?

Comment: See [this previous question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32390/differences-among-expression-and-idiom-as-well-as-colloquial-and-vernacular/32391#32391). If that doesn't answer your question, please be more specific.

Comment: I am hoping to learn if we could use these words interchangeably? The words are pretty similar.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks. When I searched the site about the question, that question did not come up.

Answer (score 5):

The Vernacular refers to the native language of a person/persons, and has established norms. A colloquialism refers to an informal way of speaking. Technically, a colloquialism exists within a vernacular (because everyone has a mother language and that language will have colloquialisms). Another difference is that "vernacular" refers to a language, while "colloquialism" refers mainly to individual words.

A colloquialism is a type of informal word used for fast speech: *gonna* instead of going to, *wanna* instead of want to, *kid* instead of child (in an instance where the speakers know they are not referring to young goats instead), *coke* instead of coca-cola, etc.